# Gmail forward set "reply-to" header

Tags: gmail, email-headers

Is there any way I can forward all email messages from a Gmail account to a number of other email accounts and set the reply-to (or from) header as the Gmail's account?

So multiple people can use one email to communicate to everyone, without having to worry about changing the to email when clicking reply?

Comment: This is what Google Groups (or any other mailing list) is for.

Comment: indeed, but I was hoping I could do something were I dont need to force people to get a google account for example.

Comment: You don't need a Google account to participate in a Google Groups list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ale said in a comment, this is what Google Groups are for. You don't need a Google account to participate in a Google Groups list. You can also use other mailing list software.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can't do that with most of the email clients and webmail software. The things you are trying to do are usually a result of email addresses / groups belonging to Microsoft Exchange.